# YouTube Live Streaming doesn't work on CentOS

Tags: centos, chrome, ffmpeg, youtube

My laptop has Ryzen 2200U with a Radeon Vega 3 and I am using it with CentOS 8, KDE 5 and Chromium version 81.

I installed `x264` and `gstreamer-plugin-`blah stuffs, but still both Konqueror and Chromium says: `Your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats available.` and YouTube suggests for HTML5 support but according to https://www.youtube.com/html5, my browser supports HTML5.

Strangely, if I copy the streaming link and paste it into VLC, it works perfectly.

I googled it, but most of answers are about for Ubuntu's, and even answer for Fedora doesn't work since `epel` seems to not have `chromium-plugin-ffmpeg` package.

I also installed `RPM Fusion`, but there wasn't either.

so is there an equivalent on CentOS, and, if there is, what package(s) is/are I have to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't feel aversion to proprietary software I'd recommend installing Google Chrome as it supports H.264 by default: https://www.google.com/chrome/

As for Konqueror, installing `gstreamer1-plugin-openh264` might help but I'm not sure it's available for CentOS 8.

Comment: Sadly, `gstreamer1-plugin-openh264` isn't in EPEL for CentOS **8**. so I may switch to proprietary Chrome. I appriciate it.